# How can I navigator to a specific page in SearchDelegate

Tags: flutter

Is there any recommended SearchDelegate article or video?
I found a simple SearchDelegate demo,
but I have no idea how can I navigator the search result to a specific page.

[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by **switch**,  although I know it is not a good method.
Because then I'm going to have a long list of switch